# MvvmCross Polymorphic MvxListView crashing app

Tags: listview, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have the following code:

```
public void LoadComments ()
        {
            IsLoading = true;
            Console.WriteLine (Recomendation.Recomendation.ID);
            List<Comment> tmpcomments = CommunicationManager.Comments.GetComments (Core.AppConfiguration.Instance.User.ID, Page, Recomendation.Recomendation.ID);
            Dispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction (() =>
            {
                try
                {           
                        Comments.Add (Recomendation);       
                    foreach (var item in tmpcomments)
                    {
                        var vm = new CommentViewModel (item);
                        Comments.Add (vm);
                    }

                    IsLoading = false;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            });
        }
```

Every once in a while I get the following exception from this line: `Comments.Add (Recomendation);`

The exception is swallowed and crashes the application. Here is the stack trace:

```
[mono-rt] Stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.wrapper_native_0x4083eba1 (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00026, 0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00062, 0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.8.2-branch/a25a31d0/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:600
[mono-rt]   at Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged () [0x00058] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.8.2-branch/a25a31d0/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-14/src/generated/Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.cs:305
[mono-rt]   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxAdapter.RealNotifyDataSetChanged () <IL 0x00003, 0x00087>
[mono-rt]   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00002, 0x00063>
[mono-rt]   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxAdapter.OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged (object,System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00003, 0x0006b>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___object_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0005a, 0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&) <IL 0x00030, 0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo) <IL 0x0004a, 0x0027f>
[mono-rt]   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (object,object[]) <IL 0x00006, 0x0008f>
[mono-rt]   at Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription`2.OnSourceEvent (object,TEventArgs) <IL 0x00032, 0x00173>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs (object,System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00059, 0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00017, 0x000f7>
[mono-rt]   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem (int,T) <IL 0x0001c, 0x000d3>
[mono-rt]   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add (T) <IL 0x0000f, 0x000c3>
[mono-rt]   at TasteITAndroidClient.RecomendationPageViewModel/<>c__DisplayClass7.<LoadComments>b__6 () [0x00002] in e:\Software Projects\TasteIT\TasteIT\TasteITAndroidClient\Shared\ViewModels\Pages\RecomendationPageViewModel.cs:86
[mono-rt]   at Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxMainThreadDispatcher.ExceptionMaskedAction (System.Action) <IL 0x00003, 0x00093>
[mono-rt]   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidMainThreadDispatcher/<>c__DisplayClass1.<RequestMainThreadAction>b__0 (object) <IL 0x00006, 0x0004b>
[mono-rt]   at Android.App.SyncContext/<Post>c__AnonStorey2E.<>m__1F () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.8.2-branch/a25a31d0/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:23
[mono-rt]   at Java.Lang.Thread/RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.8.2-branch/a25a31d0/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:32
[mono-rt]   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (intptr,intptr) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.8.2-branch/a25a31d0/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-14/src/generated/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:71
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.3cc3d616-7089-41d9-a968-d58c100cf59e (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00011, 0x0003b>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.3cc3d616-7089-41d9-a968-d58c100cf59e (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00022, 0xffffffff>
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
[mono-rt] a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
[mono-rt] used by your application.
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt]
```

As stated this is a polymorphic MvxLiseView using the following adapter:

```
public class PostPageListAdapter :MvxAdapter
    {

        public PostPageListAdapter(Context context, IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext)
            : base(context, bindingContext)
        {
        }

        public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
        {
            var item = GetRawItem(position);
            if (item is RecomendationViewModel)
                return 0;
            return 1;
        }

        public override int ViewTypeCount
        {
            get { return 2; }
        }

        protected override View GetBindableView(View convertView, object source, int templateId)
        {
            try
            {
                if (source is RecomendationViewModel)
                {
                    templateId = Resource.Layout.ListHeader_RecomendationPage;
                    return base.GetBindableView (convertView, source, templateId);
                }
                else
                if (source is CommentViewModel)
                {
                    templateId = Resource.Layout.Template_Comment;
                }
                View v = base.GetBindableView (convertView, source, templateId);//          
                return v;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new View (convertView.Context);
            }
        }
    }
```

It is not cached anywhere and simply crashes my app. Its getting very frustrating...

Comment: Can you give any more info on when `Every once in a while` is - if you can identify what causes the crash, then that might help debug the problem. Does it happen if you turn some of your polymorphic types off - does that stop the problem and help identify where the issue is? Is it for specific Recommendation values? Or does the problem occur if you only add the Recommendation or only Comment objects? If all else "frustrates" you, can you upload a simple reproducing sample to a github repo?

Comment: Also, the `catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new View (convertView.Context);
            }` block looks very dangerous

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response.
The Load comments is called whenever i navigate to the comments page. I can navigate to it and then back for 10 times and then it might crash, I cant say X times every once in a while it just crashes. and that try catch was just added to see if I can catch the exception. I have also tried it from the UI thread but it is only when I add the Recomendation object, once its removed It never crashed no matter how much i tried.

Comment: As the question stands today, you are the only one who can debug this - so my main suggestions stay the same - try making your list non-polymorphic - does the exception still occur? Can you repro this problem in a simpler test project that you can share in this question (edit question) or on github? Since the problem disappears when you remove Recommendation (but continue to add Comments) then this suggests there is a problem in Recommendation somewhere - but only you have the code for this.

Comment: What do you mean by making the list non-polymorphic? I have many places where I have lists of Recomendations and everything is good. I am actually doing this because I want to display an item and then its comments in a scrollable view. I tried using a hardcoded design for the Recomendation followed by a listview for the comments all inside a scrollview but the listview is not behaving properly. is there a better solution other than a polymorphic list? I am actually feel its kind of a hack to achieve the UI I need

Comment: I am saying *you are the only one who can debug this* currently - as only you have the crashing code in front of you - and I am simply suggesting experiments you can try.